# How to Create Flows for these conditions?

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning, salesforce-communities, salesforce-flow

Flow Task

Create below three User Lookup fields Account-
Assigned Attorney
Assigned Paralegal
Managing Attorney

When an event is created, automatically add each of the users in these specific “fields” on an account as an attendee to each event at the point the event is created;
Assigned Attorney
Assigned Paralegal
Managing Attorney

For all future events on an Account calendar, when an assignment in one of the three fields below changes, automatically update the attendees on the event, removing any removed attendees and adding any added attendees.
Assigned Attorney
Assigned Paralegal
Managing Attorney

Recently I learned flows in salesforce and i tried this problem but didn't find out that how to approach this.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how far you got with your flow, but I'll assume it was a triggered flow / autolaunched flow, and that you're aware of the eventrelation object that links invitees to events - see reference here (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_eventattendee.htm).

So, you'd have a Flow triggered by event creation where the event is linked to an account (aka WhatId starts with '001'). This flow would retrieve the ids from the fields you described, build a list of eventrelation records and insert them.

You'd need another Flow triggered by account update where one or more of those fields change. You'll need to check each for a change and if changed, remove the old matching eventrelation record and create a new one to reflect the new invitee.

That should cover it. Give it a shot.

Comment: Can you please Explain a Little Bit More...

Comment: Which bit? Just give it a shot - you’ll do great and learn heaps! 